# A word for "able to cause empathy or sympathy"? Sympathizable?

Tags: nouns

I feel like there's a word that's buried in my head that's refusing to answer my calls, that means to "elicit empathy".

Any help would be appreciated. It might be a word that doesn't have the word "able" in it. Something like "poor", but without the connotation of being depraved. The best I can come up with is "relatable".

Comment: I think the word you are after is *reflexive*, which according to the [Merriam-Webster online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reflexive) means of, relating to, or capable of reflection (empathy?).

Comment: Look up the synonyms for "pathetic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sympathetic* is the first word that comes to mind: it can mean both feeling sympathy and causing sympathy. Here are the two relevant definitions from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> Tending to elicit sympathy or to induce a feeling of rapport; also *loosely*, pleasant, likeable. (Example: 1900 Beerbohm in *Sat. Rev.* 10 Mar. 295/2 "The true Don Juan‥is‥not a ‘sympathetic’ part.")
>
> Feeling or susceptible of sympathy; sharing or affected by the feelings of another or others; having a fellow-feeling; sympathizing, compassionate. (Example: 1867 Dickens Let. 6 Mar. (1999) XI. 327 "An unusually tender and sympathetic audience.")

Comment: Same goes for *empathetic* and *pathetic*.  Unfortunately all of these seem to call other meanings to mind first.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

> **[piteous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/piteous)** evoking or deserving pity;  pathetic

or

> **[pitiable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pitiable)** evoking or deserving pity; lamentable

Definitions are from dictionary.com.

Comment: To me this has a negative connotation, and I'm trying to avoid that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of like the term "identifiable". It fits well in my mind into the immediate meaning of the words, sympathy especially. It doesn't fit as well with empathy, however, which is probably what you want.

Comment: See the answers by Nicholas and D Krueger and edit your answer along their model.  That is, cite someone other than your own authority.

Answer (score 0):

How about deplorable, distressing, lamentable, dolorous, heartbreaking or distressing?

Answer (score -1):

"Understandable" could be another option--one with less of a "piteous" connotation.

Comment: See the answers by Nicholas and D Krueger and edit your answer along their model.  That is, cite someone other than your own authority.